# Reutilizar diseño en html

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, vue.js

Estoy tratando de reutilizar un componente que he creado con vue.js este contiene el diseño de un cuadro con un logo y titulo lo que quiero hacer es reutilizar esa vista o diseño ya que con vue.js no puedo utilizar v-for con un contenedor. Lo que tengo en mente es obtener de la base de datos la cantidad de registro y si hay 5 que se cree 5 veces esa vista o diseño es algo como el recyclerview de android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione el problema es que debía utilizar el ciclo `v-for` con un segundo argumento:

En vez de :

```
<li v-for="item in items"></li>
```

Usar:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in items"></li>
```